# How to calculate total number of entries per state using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "data" with a column "name" "state" and a few more

```
name     state
peter     MN
john      NY
jay       NY
sam       CO
jack      TX
jill      NO
```

I want to calculate the number of entries per state and want my output as follows for example:

```
NY: 125
MN: 21
CO: 17
TX: 10
NO: 59
```

etc...

I have a query like this

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM `data` GROUP BY state;");
$nums = $stmt->rowCount();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo "<tr>
       <td>" . $row["state"] . "</td>
       <td>$nums</td>
     </tr>";
}
```

This displays every state in my table but does not return the corresponding number of entries for that state. This only returns the number of states i.e. 50. How can I display the number of entries per state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem not to be referring to the column which has the count. Try aliasing it an referencing the alias in your PHP code:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT state, COUNT(*) cnt FROM `data` GROUP BY state;");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>
       <td>" . $row["state"] . ":</td>
       <td>" . $row["cnt"] . "</td>
     </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(name) as occurances,state FROM `data` GROUP BY state;");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo "<tr>
       <td>" . $row["occurances"] . "</td>
       <td>" . $row["state"] . "</td>
     </tr>";
}
```

Try this version,select the names only